# Needing to reformat a timecode string in XLS

Tags: xslt

I am needing to do the following in XLS.  Here's an example XML:

```
<timecode>01;02;03;04</timecode>
```

I need a function to convert it to...

```
<timecode>01:02:03;04</timecode>
```

I just need to change the first 3 instances of the semicolon and turn it into a colon.  I'm needing it to reformat the return value of `<xsl:value-of>` seen below:

```
        <Bug___Watermark___Call_Us__ONLY__BUG___for_TBNTCC__TC_IN>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="locators/locator[color = 'Magenta'][1]">
                    <xsl:value-of select="locators/locator[color = 'Magenta'][1]/timecode"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>18:00:00;00</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>   
        </Bug___Watermark___Call_Us__ONLY__BUG___for_TBNTCC__TC_IN>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Michael's answer is probably as good as you'll get with the information given, but if your fields aren't always the same size, you could use this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(
  substring-before(timecode, ';'), ':',
  substring-before(substring-after(timecode, ';'), ';'), ':',
  substring-after(substring-after(timecode, ';'), ';')
  )"/>
```

It's a little convoluted, and much less scalable if you ever try using it for more than the first two `;`'s, but it's more tolerant of fields with different sizes.

Comment: Anything is possible, but I believe it's a safe bet that "timecode" is `hh:mm:ss;ff`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you could look at it:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(translate(substring(timecode, 1, 8), ';', ':'), substring(timecode, 9, 3))" />
```